# What do sapd, skysapd, sksapd, and ksapd do?

Tags: security, malware

Does anyone know what sapd, skysapd, sksapd, ksapd do? Are they viruses? I tried clamav it didn't recognized them as viruses.

[image: my htop]

I also realized that my /etc/rc.local has multiple copies of this:

```
nohup /etc/cupsdd > /dev/null 2>&1&
cd /etc;./ksapd
cd /etc;./kysapd
cd /etc;./atdd
```

Comment: This looks suspicious but I'm not qualified enough to know though a quick google search shows that it might be a rootkit.

Comment: It's a botnet called "BillGates"
https://github.com/ValdikSS/billgates-botnet-tracker

Comment: you can refer to http://lpages.info/billgates-linux-botnet/ . solve problem atddd, cupsdd, cupsddh, ksapdd, kysadd,sksapdd, skysapdd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a backdoor / DDoS trojan. Check your `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.*` files for multiple cronjobs that download and execute those files. (see https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary//17282)

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: kill those processes, remove the cronjobs, remove the executables in `/etc/`, maybe you should move `/usr/bin/wget` to your home directory to make sure as long as you remove the stuff.

Answer (score 4):

[sapd](http://sapd.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a legitimate process to be running in Linux. However, the others are under investigation as per the well-regarded [SANS](http://isc.sans.org/diary/Unfriendly+crontab+additions/17282) as well as [a savvy user](http://hackervisions.org/index.php/i-got-myself-hacked/), so I would backup all your data **NOW.**

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: 1 Do that backup    2 follow the tip from _chaos_ above

Answer (score 1):

Actually SAPD is- A SIMPLE E-MAIL SECURITY DAEMON

> The protocol used to send a-mail, the SMTP, has a severe flaw, that is
>   the fact it doensn't require passwords. Due to this fact, the e-mail
>   server is vulnerable to all kinds of abuse via the Internet, like SPAM
>   relaying and origination of e-mail with the sender's address forged.
>
> SAPD is a daemon designed to protect a Sendmail server against such
>   abuses, demanding the user fetches (reads) his e-mails before he can
>   start sending. As fetching e-mail requires an username and password,
>   we have here a good authentication method that prevents misuse of the
>   SMTP protocol.
>
> This kind of authentication is called SMTP-After-POP3, because it
>   allows sending e-mail (SMTP) only after fetching e-mail (POP3). Hence
>   the name SAPD, that means "SMTP After POP3 Daemon".

For more information : [Documentation](http://sapd.sourceforge.net/doc.html)